# Set day of month in calendar android

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm not a frequent programmer for android and do not really understand why this happens:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, anio);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mes);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dia);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, hora);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuto);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); 
    Log.i("ET", "Day: " +  dia );
    Log.i("ET", "CalDAy: " +  c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
    Log.i("ETCalendar", "Tactual "+ formatter.format(c.getTimeInMillis()));
    return c.getTimeInMillis();
```

This is the LogCat:

```
I/ET(27819): Day: 16 11-16 19:13:38.656: 
I/ET(27819): CalDAy: 17 11-16 19:13:38.656: 
I/ETCalendar(27819): 4Tactual 17/11/2013 07:13
```

A possible solution that comes to mind is:

```
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dia - 1);
```

but would that work?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem? Please put what's not working as expected, as it will make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that I assigned a 16 day and when I recover a line after is a 17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that HOUR is used to define a hour in 12-hour format.

Change your code:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
```

to:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
```